# Unable to build clickhouse using cygwin on Windows Server 2012

Tags: build, cygwin, clickhouse

I'm trying to build the latest clickhouse release (v1.1.54292-stable) in cygwin (mintty-2.7.9) on Windows server 2012 (build 9600).
I've picked and installed these additional packages in cygwin:

```
automake 10-1
automake 1.15.1-1
cmake 3.6.2.-1
gcc 6.3.0-2
g++ 6.3.0-2
gccmakedep 1.0.3.-1
git 2.14.1-2
libboost_system 1.63.0-1
libmcpp-devel 2.7.2-2
libmysqlclient-devel 10.1.26-1
libpcreposix0 8.40-3
libpoco-devel 1.7.9-1
libpoco-49 1.7.9-1
libtool 2.4.6-5
make 4.2.1-2
mcpp 2.7.2-2
poco 1.7.9-1
python3 3.6.1-1
```

I'm following the official [instructions](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/development/build.html) so I ran:

```
export THREADS=$(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo)
export CC=gcc
export CXX=g++
export CMAKE_LEGACY_CYGWIN_WIN32=1
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make -j $THREADS
```

The compilation error I'm getting is this:

```
In function ‘CityHash_v1_0_2::uint128 CityHash_v1_0_2::CityMurmur(const char*, size_t, CityHash_v1_0_2::uint128)’:
/home/user/ClickHouse/contrib/libcityhash/src/city.cc:261:3:
error: ‘ssize_t’ was not declared in this scope
    ssize_t l = len - 16;
```

If I `grep` the `/usr/include/sys/types.h` for `ssize_t` it's properly defined there, but for some reason the compiler can't find it.

Thanks for any advice...

Comment: Why have you tried to do that in the first place?

Comment: We have restricted environment Windows server 2012 and we wanted to use ClickHouse.

Comment: Good luck! You will need it.